# Reference previously declared value in HELM values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a HELM Chart with a few requirements (i.e. subcharts).

When deploying that chart, I use a `values.yaml` containing all the values for both the main chart and the subcharts :

```
globalFoo: "bar"

subchart1:
  foo: subchart1-{{ globalFoo }}

subchart2:
  localFoo: "bar2"
  foo: subchart2-{{ subchart2.localFoo }}
```

I'd like to achieve two things :

- Reference a previously declared global variable (i.e. in the global chart scope) in a subchart value *(subchart1.foo* in my example)
- Reference a previously declared local variable in the same subchart scope *(subchart2.foo* in my example)

The exemple above doesn't work. I tried several syntaxes and none of them worked. I didn't find anything like that in the HELM documentation.

Is it doable ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently (as of Helm version 3) this is not supported.

A similar issue is discussed in [Proposal: Allow templating in values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2492)

And is rejected for several reasons. One of them [stated by the creator of Helm](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2492#issuecomment-304110843)

> The bigger constraint is that the values.yaml file MUST always be a valid YAML file.

And also in [Support for using {{ values }} within values.yaml](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2133#issuecomment-287451865)

> the file that is passed into the template engine as a source of data for templates is itself not passed through the template engine. We almost definitely will not do that because it gets very confusing for users. It also breaks both standard YAML compatibility and backward compatibility with all existing Helm versions.

And last but not least [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2492#issuecomment-413635332)

> **The tl;dr**
> At its most simple, the reason behind not wanting to do this is you don’t template the file that provides the values that you template with. Furthermore, this feature will be made obsolete by Helm 3
>
> ...
>
> **Obsolete by Helm 3**
> In Helm 3 as part of the eventing/hook system, we will allow Lua-based modification of values in a much easier way than having to template them out. Seeing as we are well underway with development for Helm 3, adding a feature with all of the drawbacks mentioned above would cause more churn than the value added. So we aren’t rejecting this outright, but are implementing it (albeit in a different way) for Helm 3

But the mentioned [support via Lua](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5084) has been closed with this comment

> We should close this as Lua support is not coming anytime soon and we have other (arguably better) ideas on handling this (like WASM). This was in the plan but isn't any longer.

Answer (score 30):

> Reference a previously declared global variable in a subchart value, Reference a previously declared local variable in the same subchart scope

This can be achieved to some extent using [anchors and aliases](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/#yaml-anchors).

```
global: 
   foo: &global-foo bar
   
subchart1:
  # this verbatim copies the content of the anchor
  foo: *global-foo
  local: &subchart1-local bar 

subchart2:
  foo: *subchart1-local
```

Values can naturally be combined in a helm template:

```
kind: ConfigMap
...
data:
   FOO: "subchart2-{{ .Values.subchart2.foo }}"
```

If find yourself needing "templated values" the [`tpl` function](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) may be helpful:

```
# values 
global:
   user: foo
   pass: bar 
   dbhost: dbserver.com

mychart:
   connection: "db://{{.d.user}}:{{d.pass}}/{{d.dbhost}}"

# template
kind: ConfigMap
...
data:
   DBURL: "{{ tpl .Values.mychart.connection (dict "d" .Values.global "Template" $.Template }}"
```

Note the `(dict ...)` syntax is derived from a [hint in this helm github comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5979#issuecomment-717056059). This helps to shorten the template string by giving the ".d" context instead ".Values", i.e. `.d.user` is short for `.Values.global.user`

Comment: It's worth noting that as of Helm 3.9 anchored variables won't play well with command line's "--set" flag.

Comment: Hey ,thanks for this, I want to combine a value set from the command line into the values. The example is simple: from cli I want to pass the base domain of the app, and in the values I want to define a subdomain prepending a name something like:
`helm template ... --set domain=example.com`
and in the yaml I want to set `argocd` domain as `argocd.example.com`
```
        hosts:
        - argocd.{{ tpl .Values.domain . }}
```
But doesn't work. Suggestions?